# Php list ONLY files inside zip archive (exclude folders)

Tags: php, arrays

```
        $za = new ZipArchive();
        $za->open($source);
        for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){
            $stat = $za->statIndex( $i );
            $items = array( basename( $stat['name'] ) . PHP_EOL );
            foreach($items as $item) {
            echo $item;
            }
        }
```

This code will list all files inside a zip archive but i want to exclude folders listing. If the item in the array is a folder, i want to exclude it from the array BUT i still want to list the files inside the folder. Just don't display the folder's name in the list.

Is there a way i can detect if the item is a directory in my foreach loop (how?) or do i need to run a search on the array and look for folders then unset it (how?) ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I've never used ZipArchive or anything related to zip files in PHP, but here's a shot in the dark.  Seeing as how ZipArchive has no way of telling you whether something is a file or directory, you might be able to use the is_dir function in PHP and run it with an if.

Comment: @CBroe, sorry, but if you want to use filesystem functions you need extract zip archive.

Answer (score 3):

Your foreach is useless. It iteratate over array with one item.

Anyway there is two way to detect folder. First, folders are ended with '/'. Second folders has 0 size.

```
$za = new ZipArchive();
$za->open('zip.zip');
$result_stats = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++)
    {
    $stat = $za->statIndex($i);
    if ($stat['size'])
        $result_stats[] = $stat;
    }

echo count($result_stats);
```

Comment: Thanks ! But is there an easy way to remove it from the results instead of just not displaying it ? Problem is that i also use "echo $za->numFiles;" to display the number of files found in the archive after opening it. And if a folder name is found, i also want to remove it from the count.

Comment: Thank you sectus! "Second folders has 0 size." - Folders too, so this is not precise enought. But your first way will work. getFromIndex() returns the full entry name with a / (regardless of operating system) at the end only for folder entries.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the file size, if it's zero it's a folder.

```
    $za = new ZipArchive(); 

    $za->open('zip.zip'); 

    for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){ 
        $stat = $za->statIndex( $i );
        if($stat['size']!=0){
            echo $stat['name'];
        }

    }
```

Comment: It should be `!=0` (without quotes) since the size is given as an integer.

Comment: It works, of course, but it is poor coding style. Try changing `==` to `===` and it won't work anymore because three equal signs also check for type equality.

Comment: But empty files are not folders.

Comment: Nonsense. Files can have size 0 just fine, nothing prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

Directories have a trailling slash:

```
$za = new ZipArchive();
$za->open($source);
for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){
    $stat = $za->statIndex( $i );
    if(substr($stat['name'], -1) !== '/'){
        echo $stat['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct because some file can have a size of zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for  a simple PHP function to list files and folders but not sub-folders, here is a simple crafted function that you may test and see if it would work for you.

```
function unzip($path){

  if($path ===  null ) return 'File not found.';
    $zip = new ZipArchive();

   $entryList  = '<ul class="list-group"> ';

   if ($zip->open($path) == TRUE) {
      for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {

       //set the prerequisit inputs
       $stat =  $zip->statIndex($i); //an array of file statistics or details
       $filename =  $stat['name']; // entry name
       $size =  $stat['size']; //entry size

       //list only folders and file names but not subfolders.
       //when size is zero,its folder, list it, and when entry name
       //doesn't contain the (/), its is a file, list it.

      $isFile  =  strstr($filename, '/') === false;
      $anyFile  = preg_match('/(\..+)$/',$filename);
      $icon = ($anyFile  ? 'fa-file text-info' : 'fa-folder text-warning' );
   
      if($size == 0 || $isFile  ){
          $filename = str_replace('/','',$filename);
          $entryList .='<li class="list-group-item  ">';
          $entryList .=  '<i class="fa '.$icon.' mr-1 "></i>';
          $entryList .='<button class="btn btn-link">'.$filename.'</button></li>';
    }
 }

   $zip->close();
  }

  return $entryList.'</ul>' ;

 }
```

and here is the output:
[image: File list]